# How to access files in windows active directory with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-directory

I am trying to find out if there is a way for a ruby application to read files on a networked windows active directory folder.  This will need to be an automated process that authenticates and connects to the AD environment then reads files in a particular folder.  This is **not** a user browsing for a file and attaching it (e.g. using carrierwave or something similar).

I was thinking something along the lines of LDAP and have used the net-ldap gem to access active directory tree before (for querying user data via AD attributes, e.g. GivenName).  I guess this would need something similar.

I think it would be fair easier to write a script in windows script to do the same but wanted to be able to rule out being able to do this with ruby first.

Many thanks,

Comment: I would suggest you to try and narrow down the question to any problem that you faced when trying to do this with Ruby. Also AD is a collection of Objects but not files afaik.

Comment: Appreciate the comment on AD being a collection of objects a but not files.  Won't pursue that line of enquiry.  I don't think there is an existing GEM available to allow access to an AD share from ruby, so I guess this isn't possible.  .

Comment: I dont get something shared from AD. Can you detail the structure and what you are trying to access.

Comment: The requirement I have is to use a ruby application to find a file (the most recent created in a folder on a windows server).  It then needs to read each line and compare it with other files in the same folder to see if it can find any matches.  This needs to be an automated with no user interaction.  The ruby application would be hosted on a unix server.  The folder where the files are is on a windows server.  If all the files were on the unix server then not a problem.  They are on a different server, a windows server.  Which is the problem.

Comment: I think this might be possible by creating a share to the windows server from the unix server.  The application then accesses the share for the files.